# Proof that the Euclidean norm is indeed a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I apologize beforehand for this question. Its embarrassing I know.

Anyway, here we go.

Recall:

$$ \| x \|^2_{\mathbb{R}^2} = \sum^{n}_{i = 1} x^2_{i}$$

How do we prove its a norm?

Well if its a norm it should have the three properties:

1. Positivity $\| x \| \geq 0, \forall x \in X$ and $\| x \| = 0 $ iff $x = 0$
2. Homogeneity $\| cx\| = |c| \| x \|$
3. sub-additivity $ \| x + y \| \leq \| x \| + \| y \|$

1) the first is easy because its a sum of squares so its always positive and it can only be zero when x = 0 because thats the only way to make zero from the addition of a bunch of positive things.

2) Stuck in this one (homogeneity):

$$\| c x\|^2 = \sum^{n}_{i = 1} (cx_{i})^2 = \sum^{n}_{i = 1} c^2x_{i}^2 = c^2 \| x \|^2$$

which seems correct algebra but $c^2 \neq |c| $ which makes me doubt my answer. Anyone know whats going on?

3) for the 3rd one I think the way to do it is using "the extended triangle inequality", probably collecting like terms (and maybe some induction, not sure yet) and then your done. Have not tried this because I am very frustrated about not being able to get 2 yet. But I think this plan of attack for 3 should work.

Comment: For 2) you have squared both sides, so of course you get $c^2$...

Comment: Your work in 2 seems fine to me, just incomplete.  Note that you are trying to prove an equation with $\|cx\|$, $|c|$ and $\|x\|$, whereas you proved an equation with the squares of those three terms, $\|cx\|^2$, $|c|^2$ and $\|x\|^2.$  So you need to think of a way to "undo" the squares (not quite taking the squares roots of both sides, but something like that).

Comment: @Max thank you. I feel dum right now. Thanks.

Comment: @Pinocchio It happens to everyone time to time, don't take it hard :)

Comment: @RandyE sorry randy, not sure if I know what you mean, do you mind being explicit?

Comment: $\sqrt{c^2} = |c|$.

Comment: For 3) Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality 
$$u\cdot{v}≤∥u∥∥v∥$$

Comment: You got the equation $\|cx\|^2=c^2\|x\|^2$.  This is almost the equation you want to prove, but with everything squared.  So to get the equation you're required to prove, you need the square roots of these terms, but the square root of $c^2$ is not $c$, but $|c|$ (which is the reason for my parenthetical comment), as @danielson says.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. $cx=(cx_1,cx_2,\dots,cx_n).$
The definition for the euclidean norm is the following:

> $||x||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$

For 2, $||cx||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(cx_i)^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(c^2x_i^2)}=\sqrt{c^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}=|c|\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}=c||x||$.

You can consult, for example, this article:
https://bspace.berkeley.edu/access/content/group/2fb5bd3e-8d09-40ee-a371-6cc033d854b9/ho4.pdf

Answer (score 12):

I am grateful for the answer to my question and the comments. However, as my title says, this is a question about Euclidean norm being a norm. So for completeness I will provide the proof for 3 (sub-additivity). My proof goes like this:

$$\| x + y\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i+y_i)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i^2+y_i^2+2x_iy_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i^2+ 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i $$

Thus:

$$ \| x + y\|^2 =  \| x \|^2 + \| y\|^2 + 2 x \cdot y $$

Now lets use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality (as suggested by jimbo in the comments), we get:

$$ \| x + y\|^2 =  \| x \|^2 + \| y\|^2 + 2 x \cdot y \leq \| x \|^2 + \| y\|^2 + 2 \| x \| \| y \| = ( \| x \| + \| y \|)^2$$

which is the same as:

$$\| x + y\|^2 \leq ( \| x \| + \| y \|)^2$$

which implies:

$$ \| x + y\| \leq \| x \| + \| y \|$$

as required.

Thnx everyone! :)